# How to filter multiple line of text field using Sharepoint Rest API?

Tags: angularjs, rest, api, sharepoint

Hi I'm having trouble in filtering SharePoint documents through the use of Rest API since I'm using multiple lines of texts(Plain text) column to filter them out. It only returns null result after trying it out.

Single line of text column seems to work well but I need Multiple lines of text because the metadata exceeds the 255 char limit.

I'm new to SharePoint, please help. Thank you

Comment: the type of field (in your sharePoint list) is "Multiple lines of text" instead of " Single line of text", right?... this should be no issue... if you share your code here, I will try to help...

Comment: I'm using a button inorder to filter an external SharePoint list. Here's the click event of the button `$scope.buttonToFilter = https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/portal/subsite/Lists/List%20Summary/AllItems.aspx?stream="+stream+"&$top=1000"; ` Where in "+stream+" is the variable name for the Multiple lines of text column.

Comment: When you run this URL in the browser, what do you see?

Comment: when you just do "https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/portal/subsite/Lists/List%20Summary/AllItems.aspx" in your application and then print the response in console... what do you see?

Comment: When running this url `https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/portal/subsite/Lists/List%20Summary/AllItems.aspx` I can see all the items but when running the URL to filter it returns null value

Comment: And also, here's the url that I'm using in the function to get filtered item by the "+stream+", `url: "https://sharepoint.com/sites/portal/subsite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('"+listName+"')/items?$filter=(substringof('"+implementation+"',ImplementationPhase))",` but _$filter_ is not working

Comment: this is a rights issue... you need to enable an option (using Admin privileges) after which REST APIs work on SharePoint... $filter etc will all work after that

Comment: Disable "Require Use Remote Interfaces permission" and "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode", then you should be able to access the REST APIs

Comment: I will try it.. Will it work for the multiple lines of text? Because I read some of threads saying its sharepoint restriction.

Comment: It will definetly work... I have built SPAs with AngularJS on Sharepoint which included textarea also

Answer (score 1):

I am using the API to pull from a multiple line column, Product.

The first part is just to keep looking if empty and I keep js old school for IE 11 users. Product is defined earlier in the js as a variable based on the page, I am using this in many ways. Basically the answer to your question is check for null and instruct to continue, then else if and use indexOf().

```
for (i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
    if (data.d.results[i].Product == null) {
        continue;
    } else if (data.d.results[i].Product.indexOf(product) !== -1) {
        var xid = data.d.results[i];
        insertText(xid);
    }
}
```

The success function for the GET carries over the xid, insertText(xid). Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

go to site settings > site permissions > anonymous access... you gotta disable the check against Client Object Model permission Requirement

[image: disable the check in this pop-up]

Comment: I don't have any admin rights and I cannot access that option, is there any workaround? thank you

Comment: This is a must to enable REST APIs... you gotta ask your admin to enable this; you can find plenty of documents to justify doing this which you can share with your admin